# Using insert into with R

Tags: sql, r, insert, sqldf

I am tring to using `insert into` sql syntax in `R` to insert row in data frame but is showing the following error:

> (( error in sentax ))

Below is sample of my code:

```
Vector <- c("alex" ,"IT")
Tst <- data.frame( name.charcher(), major.charachter())
sqldf( c(" insert into Tst values (" , Vector[1] , "," ,Vector[2] , ")" , "select * from main.Tst "))
```

I hope my question is clear

Comment: `Sqldf` maybe `sqldf` ?

Comment: Would using `rbind(Tst, Vector)` not work for what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually i need to use sqldf because I am delaing with sql statments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few edits to help address the syntax error:

- use a lower case `s` in the function name (`sqldf()` instead of `Sqldf()`)
- add a comma between `","` and `Vector[2]`
- add quotes around `select * from main.Tst`

Also, to note:

- the 1d data structure for the heterogeneous content types in your `Vector <- c("alex", 32)` should be a list (rather than an atomic vector where all contents are of the same type).
- depending on what database driver you're using, `sqldf()` may return an error if you try to insert values into an empty R data frame as you have in your code. Creating the empty data frame within the `sqldf()` call is one approach to avoid this (used below in absence of knowing your database info).

For example, you could use the following to resolve the error message you're getting:

```
library(sqldf)
new <- list(name='alex', age=as.integer(32)) 
Tst <- sqldf(c("create table T1 (name char, age int)",
               paste0("insert into T1 (name, age) values ('", new$name[1],"',", new$age[1],")",sep=''),
               "select * from T1"))
Tst
# > Tst
#   name age
# 1 alex  32
```

Comment: Many thanks .. its work very well but when I tring to make the list as like below vector <- c("alex" , "IT")    new <- list( name =vect[1] , major= vect[1]) its show no such coulmn : IT

Comment: @inanva the answer was to your original question where you had a table with data types character and integer. for your new question where you've changed the 2nd data type from integer to character, you need to adapt those components accordingly: new <- list(name='alex', major='IT') 
Tst <- sqldf(c("create table T1 (name char, major char)",
               paste0("insert into T1 (name, major) values ('", new$name[1],"','", new$major[1],"')",sep=''),
               "select * from T1"))
Tst

Comment: Many thanks @julia wikerson its working fine :) .. but i want to ask if i have to many insert into statment .. how can i seperate the create statment from the insert into .. since i need all insert row to only one table T[